# How I Keep My Database Content

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

I am building a Asp.net Mvc Project with Entity Framework Code Fist Model. Let's say done this project. Next days if i change the model code first initializer will drop and create the database. This is problem what happend my thousands record, how i keep database records ? I can't keep with seed method thousands record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword is "database migrations", and they are described e.g. at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx for Code First.